# How to create a custom layer class

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

My question is pretty straight forward.

How to create a custom layer of layer type that will enable me to :

```
view.layer = nameOfCustomClass
```

I want the custom layer class to be able to set the view's layer properties such as:

```
layer.borderColor = UIColor.someColor()
layer.cornerRadius = 8
layer.borderWidth = 2
......
```

Plan is to be used as:`UIButton.layer = customLayerClass`
I am using latest swift

Answer (score 0):

Simply create subclass of `CALayer` and override `init` methods.

```
class MyCustomLayer : CALayer {
    override init() {
        super.init()
        // Customize layer properties here
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }
}
```

after you create subclass you can add it to the view like this:

```
let layer = MyCustomLayer()
view.layers.addSublayer(layer)
```

Comment: just to make sure, this can be used to set a button layer? uibutton.layer = customLayerClass ?

Comment: You can't use that syntax, but you can use `uibutton.layer.addSublayer(customLayerClass)`. `layer` property is always read-only.

Comment: why did you include the nscoder in the init method?